# Netstat with WMI and VBScript

Tags: scripting, vbscript, wmi, wmi-query, netstat

I am working on a project where I need to modify a script used for network documentation.  The current script that we use is a modified version of SYDI, [found here](http://sydiproject.com/products/sydi-server/).  What I would like to do is add to this script the ability to execute a *netstat -an* and have it returned with the rest of the report.  I was curious if anyone has used WMI and VBScript to return netstat information and how it might be able to be incorporated into this script.

NOTE: I am not trying to promote a product and I am not affiliated with the SYDI project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could run netstat and capture the result like the script here under, but much info is also available from activeX but the i would need to know what information you need exactly.

```
set sh = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell") 
set Connections = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 

call Main() 

Function Main() 
    call GetConnections() 
    call ProcessConnections() 
End Function 

Function GetConnections() 
    i = 0 
    set shExec = sh.Exec("netstat -f") 

    Do While Not shExec.StdOut.AtEndOfStream 
        Line = shExec.StdOut.ReadLine() 
        If Instr(Line, "TCP") <> 0 Then 
            Set Connection = New NetworkConnection 
            Connection.ParseText(Line) 
            call Connections.Add(i, Connection) 
            i = i + 1 
        End If 
    Loop 
End Function 

Function ProcessConnections() 
    For Each ConnectionID in Connections.Keys 
        wscript.echo ConnectionID & Connections(ConnectionID).RemoteIP 
    Next 
End Function 

Class NetworkConnection 
    Public Protocol 
    Public LocalIP 
    Public LocalPort 
    Public RemoteIP 
    Public RemotePort 

    Public Sub ParseText(Line) 
        dim i 

        For i = 5 to 2 Step -1 
            Line = Replace(Line, String(i, " "), " ") 
        Next 

        Line = Replace(Line, ":", " ") 
        Line = Right(Line, Len(Line) - 1) 
        Line = Split(Line, " ") 

        Protocol = Line(0) 
        LocalIP = Line(1) 
        LocalPort = Line(2) 
        RemoteIP = Line(3) 
        RemotePort = Line(4) 

    End Sub 

    Private Sub Class_Initialize 
        'MsgBox "Initialized NetworkConnection object" 
    End Sub 

End Class
```

EDIT: based on the comment of OP here a simplified version

```
set sh = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")  
call GetConnections()  

Function GetConnections()  
  i = 0  
  set shExec = sh.Exec("netstat -an")  
   Do While Not shExec.StdOut.AtEndOfStream  
      Wscript.Echo shExec.StdOut.ReadLine()  
  Loop  
End Function
```

Comment: I would like the full output of the _netstat -an_ command.  That is, I would like to see the whole listing of the Protocols, Local Addresses, Foreign Addresses, and State.  Ideally, this would be output into a table similar to what one can see from the command line when they run the command.  Thanks for the ideas and example and your help.