# Get Active Network Connections in VBScript from .Net Properties

Tags: .net, scripting, vbscript, wmi

There is a .NET method used for retrieving TCP and UDP connection information as listed below:

```
[Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties]::GetIPGlobalProperties().GetActiveTcpConnections()
[Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties]::GetIPGlobalProperties().GetActiveUdpConnections()
```

I was curious if there is a way to do the same via VBScript?  I would like to have the output of all of the connections, similar to a *netstat -an* output, returned in a VBscript that I am using for network documentation.  If this is possible via a WMI query, I would be interested in that as well.

Here are some links for reference to the .Net methods listed:

- [GetActiveTcpConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ipglobalproperties.getactivetcplisteners)
- [GetActiveUdpConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ipglobalproperties.getactiveudplisteners)

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to use PowerShell, which has direct access to .NET.

The other option would be to run Netstat.exe from WScript.Shell and parse the results, as per
[Netstat with WMI and VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10706401/netstat-with-wmi-and-vbscript).